# Dar estilo al contenido de un object/embed

Tags: html, css

Tengo una aplicación web que tiene un elemento `object` (que contiene un `embed`) que uso para mostrar los documentos seleccionados por el usuario.

Los documentos pueden ser PDF o ficheros de texto plano (.txt) que tengo almacenados en cadenas en base64, y lo que hago es cambiar los atributos `data` y `src` del `object` y `embed` respectivamente para que muestre el contenido. El resultado final se vería así (simplificado):

```css
object {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<object type="text/plain" data="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh">
  <embed type="text/plain" src="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh" />
</object>
```

Los PDF se ven bien, pero el texto de los .txt se ve un poco pequeño y me han pedido que lo haga más grande y ahí es donde tengo el problema. No encuentro la forma de darle estilo.

He intentado cambiado el tamaño del texto del `object` y `embed` pero el contenido no lo toma:

```
object, embed {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

También vi que Chrome toma el contenido del fichero .txt y lo pone dentro de un `pre`, así que intenté estilizar el `pre`, pero los estilos sólo se aplican a los `pre` de fuera del `object` y no a los de dentro del mismo:

```
pre {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de dar formato al contenido de los .txt en el `object`? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Si los documentos son escritos en el servidor y accedidos a través del mismo dominio, podrías obtener el documento interno del `object` con JavaScript y aplicar los estilos correspondientes.

Comment: @Guz ¿Cómo sería eso? Los documentos los recibo en base64 y no tengo información de dónde o cómo se almacenan. Hago una llamada a un servicio que me devuelve la cadena

Comment: ¿Puedo sugerir una respuesta utilizando un lenguaje de `backend`? Por ejemplo en `PHP`

Comment: @Marcos ¿qué tienes en mente? Tengo un object/embed al que le cambio el data/src de manera dinámica (recibo los datos en base64 via AJAX), y parece que no hay manera de estilizarlo usando CSS/JS porque se considera un contexto diferente. Si tienes algo que funcione en el lado del servidor, podría valer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución que se podria aplicar (como comento [@gugadev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108940/dar-estilo-al-contenido-de-un-object-embed#comment202004_108940)) es visualizar el `documento` (es decir el valor en base64) en otro archivo hosteado en el mismo dominio que el archivo donde se lo requiere.

Al hostear ambos archivo bajo el mismo dominio, el navegador **NO** aplica las restricciones para `CORS` y por ende, podremos acceder al `contentDocument` creado por el `object`.

### Ejemplo:

*index.html*

```
<style>
object {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<object id="object" data="//content.php?contentType=text/plain&base64=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"></object>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('object');
element.onload = function() {
  var objectDoc = element.contentDocument.documentElement,
    pres = objectDoc.getElementsByTagName('pre');

  // Cambiamos el estilo
  pres[0].style.fontSize = '3em';
}
</script>
```

*content.php*

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: " . $_GET['contentType']);
echo base64_decode($_GET['base64']);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://main.xfiddle.com/8a1c8dac/htmlobject.php)

Comment: Parece que esta es la única manera de hacerlo por las restricciones de seguridad del navegador.